# Progressive loss of audio

Tags: drivers, audio

A few months ago, and out of the blue, I started experiencing the following. When using any application that does sound (e.g. a game, or video chat), after a while sound starts "deteriorating" - first a bit of noise, then the audio gets progressively worse until it goes completely mute, and all is left is some low volume white noise. Sometimes it comes back sometimes it doesn't.

I haven't been able to figure out what's going on. Here are some more details:

- Hardware: MSI GT683DX laptop

  - Audio device (as reported by lspci): Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
- Software: tried on Fedora 20, Ubuntu 16.04, and Windows 10

  - They all exhibit the same problem, across a range of applications, so I'm thinking it's not a driver issue (or a software issue in general).
- This affects the internal speakers but also headphones, so I'm thinking it's not the speakers themselves.
- I have the vague feeling that it may be related to CPU temperature, but I don't have conclusive evidence.

Have you experienced anything similar? Any idea where or what to look for? If it's a hardware issue, how can I verify that, and is there any way to fix it (e.g. find and replace a faulty capacitor)?

Comment: I would think you have one of the following issues. firmware, BIOS settings, or hardware failure going one. Have you checked the firmware version to make sure you are at the latest version? What about BIOS settings have they changed? If both are good I bet you have hardware failure going on.

Comment: I haven't changed the BIOS settings or upgraded the firmware for *years* before this started happening... so I guess it's hardware failure.

Comment: This is a laptop that is otherwise fine, any way to diagnose and repair this kind of thing?

Comment: No way to really test it that I know of unless you have a spare motherboard for that laptop that is known to be working.

Comment: Hardware fault related to temperature is also my first idea. Possibly defect fan. Do you have sensors that show the internal temperature (`lmsensors` under Linux)? Can you correlate that with the "badness" of the effect? (put CPU in idle/hibernate after effect starts to decrease temp, then look again)

Comment: @dirkt That's a brillaint idea, I'll start tracking that! Will clean the fans too.

Comment: Are you doing your linux tests from a liveCD ?  +1 get a graph of the temp sensor readings.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage dirkt - After some experimentation, definitely seems related to temperature - sound starts coming back when the computer cools down.

Will clean every fan and vent - other than that, any way to actually fix this? For whatever reason I still suspect it may be a faulty capacitor. Also buying an USB sound card as a backup :(